# Order of Convergence for a sequence converging to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

How would you go about proving the following:

Consider a sequence $e_n$ of positive real numbers converging to zero such that $e_{n+1} = Ke^r_n$,  where r is the order of convergence and $K > 0$ is a constant.

Show that $$\frac{log \ e_{n+1}}{log \ e_n}\to r, \qquad as \ n\to \infty. $$

Answer (score 0):

Follows from
$$
\frac{\log e_{n+1}}{\log e_n} = \frac{\log K + r \log e_n}{\log e_n}
= \frac{\log K}{\log e_n} + r,
$$
since $\log e_n \to - \infty.$

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: If you like the answer, you can upvote it (clicking the up arrow). I see that this is the first question you have asked.

Comment: I've upvoted it, however as it is the first question I've asked and therefore I have a low reputation, it doesn't show it publicly

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I had forgotten.